# Can't save Button Position in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a user control with 10 small buttons (20 x 20).  I am using the following code to allow the user to drag each button along the x axis only.
I then want to save its X location to a list which can be saved as part of an XML file and then be loaded with the same button locations the next time the app runs.  For some reason, I can't save button location.  Even the message box doesn't show.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    private Point p;

    private void button2_mousedown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;
        Button b1 = ((Button)sender);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void button2_mousemove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;
        Button b1 = ((Button)sender);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            b1.Left = e.X + b1.Left - p.X;
        }
        int idx = int.Parse(buttonName) - 1;
        scriptIconLocation[idx] = b1.Left;
        //MessageBox.Show(scriptIconLocation[idx].ToString(), "saved location");
        savedSettings.ScriptIconLocation = scriptIconLocation;
        saveSettingsXML(savedSettings);
    }
```

Comment: You must ask two separate questions. First about buttons moving, second about saving/loading data to/from xml.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The buttons move just fine.  I just can't save the locations.

Comment: Well, show your saving code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move buttons use the following code. Subscribe each button on this event handler.

```
private void Button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        button.Left = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X;
    }
}
```

The `MouseDown` event is not necessary.

---

Do not save data in xml with every mouse movement, because it's very inefficient.

Do this, for example, when the form is closed. And read the data when the form is loaded.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Array of your buttons.
    var buttons = userControl.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();

    var xml = XElement.Load("buttons.xml").Elements("X").ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].Left = (int)xml[i];
    }
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    var buttons = userControl.Controls.OfType<Button>();

    var xml = new XElement("Buttons",
        buttons.Select(b => new XElement("X", b.Left)));

    xml.Save("buttons.xml");
}
```

Comment: Worked fine once I changed it to a MouseUp handler.  Question.  Is it possible to left drag without triggering the Click event or right drag without triggering a context menu event?